# How can I correctly shift this uint64_t number?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, endianness

I'm writing a small test program that converts 64-bit numbers from little-endian to big endian format.

```
int main(void){
    uint64_t value1 = 1234;
    uint64_t value2 = 0;
    uint64_t constant = 0xFF00000000000000;
    uint8_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int8_t shift = 56 - 16 * i;    // Gives me the sequence 56, 40, 24, 8.
        value2 |= (value1 & constant) >> shift;
        constant = constant >> 2;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int8_t shift = 16 * i + 8;     // Gives me the sequence 8, 24, 40, 56.            value2 |= (value1 & constant) << shift;
        constant = constant >> 2;
    }

    printf("\n\nvalue1: %" PRIu64, value1);
    printf("\nvalue2: %" PRIu64, value2);
}
```

It's a little convoluted, but it's the bitwise shift operations I have a problem with. The line

```
constant = constant >> 2;
```

doesn't give me what I expect. I expect `0xFF00000000000000` to become `0x00FF000000000000` after one loop, and so on. Instead, it becomes `0x3FC0000000000000`.

I assume there's also a similar problem with the other shift operations. Can anyone explain?

My first guess is that bitwise operators only work correctly on 32-bit numbers. In which case, I could cast a 32-bit pointer and deal with each 32-bit block one at a time. But I'd like to avoid that since it's even more convoluted.

Comment: `constant >> 2` shifts the number by two *bits* to the right.

Comment: To move one byte over: `constant >> 8`

Comment: Note: Calling a **variable** "constant" is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Loops as `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)` would spare you the magic number `72`.

Comment: Why would there be a restriction of the shift operator for 64 bit types? (retorical question, there is none, of course). Your pointer approach otoh would invoke undfined behaviour.

Comment: Sorry abut the typos guys. I was in a rush.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I knew it would be something that simpler I was overlooking. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane My loop doesn't look like that. And I don't need 72. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Olaf, I agree, it was just some quick code to try out an idea.

Comment: That's right, your loops are `for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` which requires you to use the magic number 72 (which you deny) which has no immediate connection with the problem. If you use the more usual 0-based loops the 72 can be replaced by 64, and is more obviously relevant. It would also save you having to subtract 8 in the second loop. *In general* it is a newbie mistake to use 1-based loops the way you do - almost always, they are better as 0-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The >> operator does a bit-shift by the amount of bits at the right of the operator. You should use `constant >> 8` if you want to move over 1 bytes (2 nibbles). It works exactly the same no matter the size of the variable on which the shift is being applied.

Comment: Definitely a facepalm situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This has to be when working with bitwise operator. Look at the simple explanation below.

In your case `0xFF0000...000` is actually `0b111111110000...000` in binary representation. When you must have read about 0000 to 1111 in binary is actually 0 to F in hex representation. This bitwise operator operates bit-level so this hex representation needs to be broken to a binary before we look into further.

Now shifting 2 bits give out `0b001111111100...000`. Observing closely, this is `0b<0011><1111><1100>00...000` which is actually `0x3FC00...000`

Hope it explained!